# Crop out background in an image - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, numpy-slicing

I have the following image extracted. Background value is 170, I need to extract the polygon with a minimum of 170 values. 
for the image is like below
[image]

I would like to have a processed image as below

[image]

I can implement a nested for loop and iterate through until i find the minimum index of the column and find the maximum index of the column number for each row and then extract the region.. but Im interested in a numpy query more efficient solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

One strategy would be to label the image, get the label for one of the corners, as one sample for the background color and create a mask of that color. So, the inverted mask area is the one we are trying to crop into. For the cropping, we will take inspiration from [`Crop black border of image using NumPy : Answer post`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132934/).

Here's the implementation -

```
import cv2
from scipy.ndimage import label

im = cv2.imread('xYTKn.png') # read in input image
L,_ = label(im)
mask = (L!=L[0,0]).any(-1)
out = im[np.ix_(mask.any(1), mask.any(0))]
cv2.imwrite('output.png',out)
```

Input -

[image]

Output -

[image]

---

**Approach #2**

Another similar strategy would be to convert to grayscale upfront, then label and get the required mask, like so -

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
L,_ = label(gray)
mask = (L!=L[0,0])
out = im[np.ix_(mask.any(1), mask.any(0))]
```

#### Benchmarking

We will time the proposed solutions on the given sample image. The mask creation is different between the two approaches. So, we will time those sections only -

```
In [70]: %%timeit
    ...: L,_ = label(im)
    ...: mask = (L!=L[0,0]).any(-1)
47.4 ms ± 2.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [71]: %%timeit
    ...: gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ...: L,_ = label(gray)
    ...: mask = (L!=L[0,0])
2.59 ms ± 20.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```